# Android TranlateAnimation background doesn't work

Tags: android, translate-animation

I am usig TranlateAnimation to showing and hiding EditText. First EditText has visibility gone. After it takes visibility visible and tranlating up. When EditText get focus backgroung of all app becomes black. When focus of EditText is lost everything becomes good. Maybe it's because I use ViewPager which contains all fragrament. What is the problem of this?
Here is code of animation:

```
private void initAnimationDown() {
    animationDown = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, height);
    animationDown.setFillAfter(true);
    animationDown.setDuration(500);
    }
private void initAnimationUp() {
    animationUp = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, height, 0);
    animationUp.setFillAfter(true);
    animationUp.setDuration(500);
    }

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    if (isChecked) {
        initAnimationUp();
        perfectEditText.startAnimation(animationUp);
        perfectEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        initAnimationDown();
        perfectEditText.startAnimation(animationDown);
        perfectEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try to unvalidate the edit text before hidding him and starting animation?

```
perfectEditText.setFocusable( false );
perfectEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode( false );
```

Comment: It does't help. But I figured what causing this bug, but I don't know how to fix it. It causing because I change visibility of EditText from GONE to VISIBLE. If from the beginning visibility of EditText set as VISIBLE everything is good. But if change it from GONE to VISIBLE and focus EditText background of app changing to black

Comment: Why setting the visibility from GONE to VISIBLE?